# Reset Community Profile Picture to Default Person Outline

Tags: community, user-profile

I have about 10 Community users with profile pictures that we want to remove and display the default outline of a person picture.  I have downloaded the user data via Data Loader and can see the fields that contain the profile picture URLs.  However, I don't seem to have the ability to update the fields via Data Loader.  They aren't available when I user the update feature.  Thoughts on how I fan remove the current profile pictures and display the default one?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ConnectAPI method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_ConnectAPI_UserProfiles_static_methods.htm) for this.

```
ConnectApi.UserProfiles.deletePhoto(communityId, userId);
```

This can be done in the developer console to get the user ids you want and then set call this method to remove their photos.